# mysql grant select privilege on only one table and some columns of it

Tags: mysql, sql, datatable, sql-grant

I have a table with around 10 columns 
I have created a user with no privileges select.

Now I want it to grant only select privileges to only that table and if possible only 2-3 columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-column-privileges

```
GRANT SELECT (col1,col2) ON database.table TO 'someuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```